# Custom thumbnail crop offsets

Tags: thumbnails

There are some WordPress plugins that allow custom crop offsets for specific thumbnails and images.

I want to do this programmatically in a theme as it inserts thumbnails with very specific crop offsets.
Is there a hook (filter, action) that can be used to customize the actual crop offset beyond the corners, as in pixels?

Answer (score 0):

The `add_image_size` function allows you to add custom image sizes with custom offsets:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/